# How do I connect from an AWS Lambda function to an ElastiCache cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I have created an ElastiCache (Redis) cluster (with Cluster mode enabled); it runs in its own VPC (say VPC-A). The Cluster is shown as 'Available' in the AWS Console.

I have written a .NET Lambda function (using the StackExchange.Redis nuget package) that attempts to connect to that ElastiCache cluster (I picked up the Configuration endpoint from the AWS Console and plugged it into my code).

`public static class RedisConnectorHelper
{
private static readonly string RedisConnectionString = "";
static RedisConnectorHelper()
{
LazyConnection =
new Lazy(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(RedisConnectionString
, Console.Out));
}

```
private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection;          

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection => LazyConnection.Value;
```

}`

I also made sure to give the Lambda, permission to access VPCs (i.e. the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole is added to the Execution Role of my Lambda).

When I run my Lambda, it fails within the `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(...)` call and I can see the following message in the logs:

`StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException with message: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code. is being handled.`

What am I doing wrong?

In an attempt to debug the problem, I tried to connect to the Redis cluster from an EC2 instance [same account, same region but different VPC (say VPC-B)] using the redis-cli utility (as explained in this link: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elasticache-connection-test)
This fails with this message
`Could not connect to Redis at <the endpoint of my cluster>: Connection timed out`

I tried a variation of this:

- I used a 'Cluster mode disabled' Redis cluster (and then try to connect to the 'Primary endpoint' instead of the 'Configuration endpoint'). Still fails the same way both from Lambda and EC2

I added a Security Group to the ElastiCache cluster that allows Incoming connections to Port 6379 from any IP address (I previously tried to allow the Security Group of my EC2 instance but the Console did not allow me to pick that SG as the EC2 instance and ElastiCache cluster are in different VPCs ); Still fails the with the same 'Connection timed out' message

Comment: Did you try following the instructions here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/access-amazon-memorydb-for-redis-from-aws-lambda/

It's for MemoryDB but it's conceptually the same as ElastiCache.